# Jquery pass extra variable to sort function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to write a common sort function. I am using jQuery for sorting. jQuery sort function only accepts two parameters as input. But I want to pass another parameter to that function. How can I do that?

Something like this:

```
 obj.sort(StringSort);
 obj2.sort(StringSort);

 function StringSort(a, b, desc)
 {
    var aText = $(a).attr(desc).toLowerCase();
    var bText = $(b).attr(desc).toLowerCase();

    if(aText == bText)
      return 0;

    return aText > bText ? 1 : -1;
 }
```

Comment: What shall desc contain for values?

Comment: @TobiasSpringer i did some more update to my post. hope you can help me now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can create a  function that returns a function. The outer function accepts the additional argument and you use the returned function as sorting callback:

```
function getStringSort(desc) {
    return function(a, b) {
        // this is a closure, you can access desc here
        // this function should contain your comparison logic or you just 
        // call StringSort here passing a, b  and desc.
    }
}

obj.sort(getStringSort(someValue));
```

The inner function has access to all parameters of the outer function since it is a [closure *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Closures).

Comment: Nice. Also a good use case for a generic ["partial application"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg575560.aspx) function.

Answer (score 4):

I don't believe jQuery has a `sort` function at all. *JavaScript* does, [on arrays](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.4.11). jQuery and JavaScript are different things (one is a library, the other is a language). ***Update***: Ah, jQuery has an undocumented `sort` (one of several functions it borrows from `Array.prototype`), but that fact is not documented and so could change from dot release to dot release. Thanks, [Felix](https://stackoverflow.com/users/218196/felix-kling).

You can't pass a third argument into the function directly. You can have the function you pass into `sort` call another function:

```
// ...assuming `desc` is in scope here here...
obj.sort(function(a, b) {
    return StringSort(a, b, desc);
});
```

The same `desc` will get passed to `StringSort` for each pair of entries being compared. `a` and `b`, of course, will be different on each call.

This works because the function we're passing into `sort` is a closure over the context in which `desc` is defined. That means the function can access `desc` (just as functions can access global variables, and for the same reason).

More on closures:

- [*Closures are not complicated*](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/closures-are-not-complicated.html)

Comment: Actually, jQuery objects have a `sort` function which is borrowed from arrays. `$().sort === [].sort` is `true`. I guess that's what the OP means.

Comment: @FelixKling: Ah, there you go. Thanks. It's not documented, so... :-)

Comment: Yeah, that's why I'm not sure whether it's a good thing or not :D (as in should be used or not).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder sorry, i was able to accept only one answer. Thanks for your help. giving upvote to this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function sortBy(field){
    return function(a, b){
        if (a.field > b.field)
            return -1;
        if (a.field < b.field)
            return 1;
        return 0;
    };
}
```